# filtering the element with format

Tags: angularjs

I'm in learning process of angularjs, so this question came into my mind.

```
{{val | number:2}}
```

This results the number value to be decimal portion to 2 like `30.12`

But trying the same thing in the $scope, I couldn't get like that.

```
$scope.example = $filter('bhojendra')('uppercase');//BHOJENDRA
$scope.val = $filter(30.12343)('number:2');//don't work
$scope.foo = $filter(30.12334)('currency');//$30.12334
$scope.foo = $filter(30.12334)('currency:"EUR"');//don't work
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency - `$filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like this way:

```
$scope.val = $filter('number')(30.12343, '2');
```

[angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) for number filter says,

> $filter('number')(number, fractionSize)
>
> number - Number to format.
>   fractionSize  (optional) - Number of decimal places to round the number to. If this is not provided
>                                then the
>                    fraction size is computed from the current locale's number formatting pattern. 
>                    In the   case of the default locale, it will be 3.

---

```
$scope.foo = $filter('currency')(30.12334);         
$scope.foo = $filter('currency')(30.12334 ,'EUR');
```

[angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) for [currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) filter says,

```
 $filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)
```

> amount - Input to filter.
>   symbol (optional) - Currency symbol or identifier to be displayed.
>   fractionSize (optional) - Number of decimal places to round the amount to, defaults to default max 
>                               fraction size for current locale

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var numberFilter = $filter('number');
$scope.foo = numberFilter('30.12334',2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)

Example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
  
  $scope.example = $filter('uppercase')('asdasdasdasda');
  $scope.val = $filter('number')(30.12343, 2); // 2 = precision
  $scope.foo = $filter('currency')(30.12334);
  $scope.bar = $filter('currency')(30.12334,"EUR ");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
{{example}}
 <br/>
  
{{val}}
 <br/>

{{foo}}
<br/>
  
{{bar}}
<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm late but here's a snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.foo = $filter('number')(30.12334, 2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    {{foo}}

  </div>

</div>
```